# Is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5},1/10]$ a PID

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, principal-ideal-domains, dedekind-domain

> Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5},1/2,1/5]$. Inverting the ramified primes $2,5$ simplifies the proof that every maximal ideal is inversible ie. the unique factorization in maximal ideals. In  $O_K=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ for any ideal there is $c \in I, N(c) \le 6 N(I)$, the latter stays true for any ideal $I$ in $R$, thus $(c) = IJ, N(J) \le 6$, since $N(1+\sqrt{-5}) = 3$ the ideals of norm $\le 6$ are principal, whence $J = (b)$ is principal and $I=(c/b)$ and $R$ is a PID.

Is it correct ? Do you know some resources on those kind of rings ? Are there some troubles in using those rings of $\Bbb{Z}[1/q]$-integers instead of $O_K$ when working with number fields ? Do they help for something, say Diophantine equations ?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13428/please-check-my-6-line-proof-of-fermats-last-theorem/13469#13469

Comment: Look up results on the *conductor ideal* to better understand what's happening here in general, e.g. see [Keith Conrad's note](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/conductor.pdf) for an introduction.

Comment: Just so it's clear to anyone else looking at this question, yes, the argument is correct. (In fact, $\mathcal{O}_K[1/2]$ is already a PID.) Given a number field $K$, one can always find a finite set $S$ (co-prime to any given fixed choice of primes) such that $\mathcal{O}_K[1/S]$ is a PID. In the example above, $\mathcal{O}[1/S]$ is a PID not just for $S = 2$ but also $S = 7,23 \ldots$. I don't see the relevant of @BillDubuque's comment.

Comment: @user670344 Let $L/K$ be an abelian extension, assume its Artin map is trivial on the primes above $2,5$, then the Hecke characters appearing in $\zeta_L$ are characters of the ideal group of $R$, defined in term of the artihmetic of $R$. With $H_K$ the Hilbert class field iff $L \cap H_K= K$ then the abelian extension can be described in term of the arithmetic of such a PID $O_K[q^{-1}]$.

Comment: I confess I'm a little confused what the point of the previous comment is and why it was addressed to me. (Also, $L \cap H_K = K$ automatically under the given hypotheses).